# Show full name from two columns in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am selecting a full name from two columns in mysql table but the input takes only one order to return the information.

```
firstname | lastname
  Amaj     |  Ato
```

With this data I want to select the full name (Amaj Ato or Ato Amaj) from one text box when the user enters Amaj Ato or vice versa (Ato Amaj).
This is what I have tried so far

```
`SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE concat_ws(' ', 'firstname', 'lastname') like '%$fullname%'; `
```

This is able to select the firstname and lastname in only one order. For instance if the user enters Amaj Ato the query gives the full name but when the user enters the firstname after the lastname ( like Ato Amaj), the query returns empty. I want the user to get the full name in any order he enters the names. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You should watch out for SQL injections and try to sanitize your input, especially ones coming in from an end-user

Comment: Yea.I wouldnt forget.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "tell" the query what you are looking for, it doesn't magically know that names could be switched. To do this, you can simply add an `OR` specifying the other valid case:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name`
WHERE concat_ws(' ', 'firstname', 'lastname') like '%$fullname%'
    OR concat_ws(' ', 'lastname', 'firstname') like '%$fullname%'
```

Comment: it seems that three names order does not work, example Koffie Adom and Mathew which are firstname and lastname respectively.When the firstname order changes,it returns empty.

Comment: @George As I said you need to explicitly tell the query what you want. You can use `concat_ws()` for the returning rows and see what it actually looks like, then maybe change the order again and add another `OR`, etc.

Comment: What I mean is, the firstname contains a value say (Koffie Adom), when the user enters Koffie Adom the row returns perfectly the firstname value (Koffie Adom), but when the user enters Adom Koffie the query returns empty.This time I am talking about only the firstname.